# Windows LDAP Authentication in C++

Tags: c++, windows, authentication, ldap

I am currently trying to authenticate users in a c++ application in Windows. I need to display a dialog for username and password and verify that they are an authenticated user on the Windows machine. Are there any libraries that allow for this functionality or a good way to go about it?

Comment: What do you need to do? access AD object? access share? access website? need more information, what you trying to do. basically kerberos/windows auth is supported build in in windows

Comment: Im just trying to check to see if a user has a valid windows user account on the machine before allowing them access to certain parts on my application. It can be any user on the machine, not just the currently logged in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178.aspx) or old `CredUIPromptForCredentials` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177.aspx) could solve your problem?

**UPDATED**: Another the most old way to authenticate a user is using of SSPI. It will not help with displaying a dialog but this can you implement yourself. You can find a very old code example (probably the first one published by Microsoft) here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548.

If you do want use LDAP API (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366102.aspx) you can use `ldap_bind_s` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366156.aspx) to verify user authentication. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366106.aspx as a code example (it is not exactly what you want, but you can understand how these API work)